# Prior for Variance Covariance Matrix

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

Why in Bayesian Hierarchical Modelling the prior corresponding to a Variance Covariance Matrix is taken to be Inverse Wishart Distribution not Wishart Distribution?